# JavaScript: Search string for expression and return error if not found

Tags: javascript

I have a form that should only allow e-mail addresses with a ".edu" domain, and I worked up some JavaScript to try to make that happen.

Form elements:

```
<input type="text" name="empEmail" id="empEmail" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"  onClick = "error();" />
<span id="empEmailError"> </span>
```

JavaScript function:

```
//Check for non-university e-mail addresses
function error() {
var email = document.getElementById('empEmail').value;
var re = /\.edu$/;
if(!email.match(re)) 
  {
      document.getElementById('empEmailError').innerHTML = "University e-mail 
      address only.";
      return false;
  }
}
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4T5qV/

I can't get it to work. Not sure what it is I'm missing.

Comment: The issue I'm finding with that fiddle is that your function is defined in the onLoad, so is not in the global scope. You may want to change that option for the fiddle. (Like this http://jsfiddle.net/4T5qV/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.test()`.

```
if(!re.test(email))
```

`.test()` returns whether the regex has matched or not.

Also, you have to use `<wrap in head>` option of fiddle

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4T5qV/2/)

Comment: `match()` returns `null` if there are no matches.

Comment: He didn't use match(). So your comment isn't relevant

Comment: @iLikePrograms My comment was referring to the content of his post as it was when I made my comment: "You have to use `.test()` as match returns array which always evaluates to true." Even as it stands now, the assertion that "You have to use `.test()`" is incorrect and has nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: Ah. Then I apologise, I was just trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem where it wasnt finding the `error` function. It could be that it was putting the `error` function in a `document.on('loaded')` function or something like that in the jsFiddle.

So the solution is to add a function to the `window`, like so:

```
//Check for non-university e-mail addresses
window.validateEduAddress = function() {
    var email = document.getElementById('empEmail').value;
    var re = /\.edu$/;
    if(!email.match(re)) {
        document.getElementById('empEmailError').innerHTML = "University e-mail address only.";
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log('woohoo');
    }
}
```

Then in your html you need to tell the `onclick` to use that function like so:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" onclick="validateEduAddress();" />
```

And just to make it easier, heres the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4T5qV/5/)

In general you should also try to avoid naming functions so generically, so instead of `error` or `fail` you should try to describe the event or functionality :)

Comment: This seems like a very odd approach to me. The correct answer is to use unobtrusive JavaScript, and that should prevent this problem.

Comment: Then post an example ?

Comment: Could you define what you mean by 'unobtrusive JavaScript' ?

Comment: [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). It basically means not peppering JavaScript throughout your markup. However, I have to backpedal one step because the typical non-jQuery place to hook up events is in `window.onload`, but that alone would not have fixed this issue because jsfiddle would overwrite that with its own event. The moral of the story is to avoid the `onLoad` dropdown option in jsfiddle because it breaks things that would ordinarily work fine.

Comment: Hmmm, good to know about the jsFiddle `onload`, I do know about *Unobtrusive Javascipt* just didnt know the term for it. Thanks for the link, it was a good read.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the cause of this issue is that you have the onLoad option selected in jsfiddle, and the result is that your inline `onclick` handler cannot find your `error` function. This is partly the fault of using inline event handlers (putting the JavaScript directly in an attribute), which is not a recommended practice.

Another problem is that you have a line break right in the middle of one of your string values, and this is causing a syntax error and preventing the code from running at all.

You should use the "no wrap in <head>" option, and unobtrusive JavaScript.

Remove the `onclick` attribute from your element:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
```

And use this:

```
function validate(e) {
    var email = document.getElementById('empEmail').value,
        re = /\.edu$/;
    if (re.test(email)) {
        document.getElementById('empEmailError').innerHTML = 
                                     "University e-mail address only.";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

window.onload = function () {
    var form = document.getElementById('submit').onclick = validate;
};
```

(I've used `re.test()` here as Amit suggests, because that does make more sense semantically in this case.)

http://jsfiddle.net/4T5qV/6/